# Connecting an Ice Maker hose directly to a tap

Tags: plumbing, water, refrigerator, ice-maker

I'm struggling to find answers on here and from my searching, and my local DIY store didn't help much.

My home is a new build, and the kitchen has a tap directly where the fridge goes... This is said tap...

[image: tap]

This tap is not used for a dishwasher or washing machine as both of those have their own taps in different parts / rooms in the house, this tap is specifically in the fridge area.

I'm looking if it's possible to connect my Fridge's Ice Maker hose directly to it somehow?

This is the connection...

[image: tube]

[image: tube end]

I've seen solutions to join this onto the actual pipe, but I'm trying to find a solution to use an actual tap, if possible?

.

Comment: I can't tell from the picture it's so small, is that tap threaded on the end? What size are the threads?

Comment: Thanks for your reply BMitch, I've updated the links to full size photos, sorry about that.

I'm not sure on thread size of the tap (apparently it's "standard"?), however I've taken a photo of the smaller one's dimensions... 
http://s23.postimg.org/3ww3n4rkb/image.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You need an adapter that will transition from your tap's thread to a **compression thread**.

Most (U.S.) refrigerators are equipped with 1/4" O.D. tubing which utilize 1/4" **compression fittings**. Your picture seems to show something larger than 1/4" O.D., my first guess would be 3/8" but if you are not in the U.S. I guess it could even be a metric size.

As for the tap size, I think it could be **garden hose thread** (adapter shown in top picture), or **pipe thread** (adapter shown in lower picture).

You will need to head to a good plumbing shop and describe your problem, bring along photos which include your measuring tape for scale.

[image][image]

Comment: Actually, now that I look, your tubing is about 6mm; .236 inches. You have 1/4" OD tubing so you need to get an adapter from your tap thread to 1/4" compression.